# ajax calls preventing preceeding DOM events

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

My question may seem similar to others asked, but none of the answers I've found address this particular **"quirk"** of

how the DOM interacts with ajax that I am having trouble with.

I have a webpage with `javascript/JQuery` functions where when a user clicks a particular button,

I am trying to make a **"loading....pease wait" animated gif (or text)** appear in a div

`(using $("#mydiv").show or document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "block"),`

and then call the main processing function (function 2) that does an ajax post to a php function to get data that the function continues to process.

Without the `post`, the loading graphic appears as expected, and when expected (before function 2 is called).  When I put in the ajax call though, the graphic does not appear (or even plain text or an alert box....basically it seems that nothing changes on the DOM) until after the ajax post is finished processing, even though the show command is called *before* the ajax post command.

I've tried everything I could find, including `beforeSend` and ajaxSetup, wrapping things in functions, etc... but nothing seems to help.  I would like to understand why and how ajax can stop DOM-altering functions that are called even before the ajax call, and if there is a way around this.

I should mention that I am using `"async:false"`.  To head off all the comments about how this is such a bad idea, the only reason I'm using ajax is to have a way to get access to my PHP code from javascript, and I actually need the results returned before moving on in the javascript function, which ties me to using synchronous calls  (even if this isn't the best way of doing things,

I'm working with inherited code, so my options are limited at this point).  If there is another way to do this without all the overhead of ajax, I'm all ears.

Thanks for your help.

```
function mainfunc(){

    function getcomparedata(){
        var returndata = null;
        $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
        $.post("rostercomparematch",{clever_district_id:clever_dist_id, sa_district_id:sa_dist_id}).done( function(data){returndata = data;});
        $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
        return returndata;
    }

var compare = null;
$("#mydiv").show();  //OR document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "block" OR $("#mydiv").text("please wait") OR alert("function called") OR..........
compare = getcomparedata();
//keep processing with compare......
}

$("#button_do_match").click( function(){  event.preventDefault();  /*$("#mydiv").show(); - TRIED SHOWING THE DIV HERE ALSO*/  mainfunc(); });
```

Comment: I think you need callbacks

Comment: I agree that restructuring my code using callbacks would help me use the calls asynchronously (and may be a solution), but unfortunately it's not practical at this moment as I would have to rewrite a lot of other code not shown here.

Comment: Bite the bullet. Be rid of async:false and refactor the code even if it takes a week to complete. When you are done, you will thank yourself even if you are not thanking me now.

Comment: I may thank you....but who's gonna pay the dental bill?  ;)  The people I'm working for may or may not have different ideas about the extra week..... If it would take significant time, I think I'd just have to drop it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `show` has a [complete](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete) callback. Execute your ajax call inside of it, that way the animation will complete, and then you'll post your request.

And obviously, it would be much better to use the async part of AJAX where you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but not working....the ajax is stopping the whole "show()" function, even with the complete or start option.